# Oracle DB not running in the VM

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-virtual-machine

All, I brought up Oracle 12C database in Azure which spun an Oracle DB on Linux 
**Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)**.I logged in remotely from a putty using the public IP. There, I could see ORACLE_HOME is set and hence my assumption is, I have correctly stood up an Oracle DB only.

echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

But I am unable to see an instance of Oracle DB running. As per the https://blogs.oracle.com/pshuff/entry/apex_in_azure blog, I am asked to run */etc/oratab* to bring-up an instance of the database but it says permission is denied. Is anyone able to successfully bring up an Oracle database inside Oracle SaaS in Azure?

I confirmed that there are no databases running by executing
echo $ORACLE_SID
and
ps -ef | grep -i pmon

and none of the above shows any databases running

Comment: I think you had better know the difference between oracle software and oracle instance. Only oracle instance starts, you could find it by using `ps -ef | grep -i pmon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check the log you provided and test in my lab. This image only installs oracle software. **There is no [oracle instance](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT89033) in it. So, you need create your own instance.**

You could refer to this [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/vm/installation-of-an-oracle-database-on-azure) and install your oracle instance.

Update:

After you create your own Oracle instance, you should add ORACLE_SID to environment variable. Save `export ORACLE_SID=yoursid` to `.bashrc`.

If you want to `tnsping` your oracle instance with Public IP, you should open port 1521(by default) on Azure NSG.

Comment: Thanks so much Walter for the pointers. This was seriously helpful. I created the database instance by running the "dbca" utility. I see this as the output on running the following:       [oracle@DBOracleRMS oracle]$ ps -ef | grep -i pmon
oracle    7735     1  0 21:44 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_DBUA4416935
oracle    9021     1  0 22:04 ?        00:00:00 ora_pmon_cdb1
oracle    9565  7391  0 22:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i pmon     but when I try to tnsping or echo the ORACLE_SID, I am not getting any results.

Comment: OK, if my answer is helpful, don't forget to mark me. Thanks.

Comment: can you please help?

Comment: You should `export ORACLE_SID=yoursid` and save it to `.bash_profile` Now, you could `echo $ORACLE_SID`

Comment: Also, you should open port `1521` on Azure NSG. You could test `tnsping 127.0.0.1:1521/sid`. If it works, it maybe a firewall issue.

Comment: I test in my lab. I only need open port 1521 on Azure NSG, I could `tnsping publicIP:1521/sid`

Comment: @SriniVasu You should `export ORACLE_SID=yoursid` save it to `.bashrc`. `.bashrc` save oralce environment variable.

Comment: All these details are being buried in comments, where they don't belong. Please edit your answer if you want to include more info.

Comment: @SriniVasu - if you have additional questions, please ask as proper questions, not as comments. This is not a discussion forum.